# Multiple Input Handling- onChange Issue

Tags: reactjs, dom, onchange

[image][[image: This is the output here after pressing add button only the URL of currentItems gets updated and not the name and URL both why???.Please provide me with a solution[][1][1]]
I want to update two variables inside object that I have initialized as CurrentItems :{ name,url} when onChange method is trigerred so what is happening is like it only updates the second most variable in the object and when I am consoling I can see changes in both the variables of this object but state is not updated for both

I have given the code aslo

Comment: Can you create code sandbox/fiddle  link?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-chatelet-z3xhg?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Sagar I have created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are receiving only one value is that we are creating a new object on Change. Try something like below :

```
handleInput = e => {
    let { currentItems } = this.state;
    currentItems.key = Date.now();
    currentItems[e.target.name] = e.target.value
    this.setState({
        currentItems
    });
};
```

If we are writing directly object in the set state it will create a new object and the previous one is lost

Comment: If you see the code above I have tried that also.Moreover I have change that in codesandbox also but still when I console the currentItems in addchangeHandle only URL is printed

Comment: Updated Answer please check @AbhishekGanotra

Comment: Thanks @Sagar for such insightful solution